# Accepting questions

Tags: support, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

I'm trying to figure out how to "accept" answers to my questions.  I have been asked about this previously or it has been suggested.  I look through all my questions and there is a check mark but none of them seem to be responding when I click on them.  I usually get the suggestion to accept more answers when I post something new.  Yet it appears too late at that point to accept any answers that I got.

I'll keep looking to see if there are any that are available for me to accept, and, if not, then I'll just add a promise in my next post to "accept" an answer.

Comment: The accepting of answers is done in javascript when you click one of the empty checkboxes on an answer. If there are javascript errors, you won't be able to accept an answer; are you seeing javascript errors? These can be viewed in the [Error Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Error_Console)